# how to fix the audit vulnerabilities problem faced in npm terminal?

Tags: node.js

While installing bebel package I faced audit vulnerabilities.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oxCi.png)

Comment: Hi there, please accept the edits the community have been kind enough to suggest. For example it's "babel", and it's best to copy paste the audit log to the body of the question surrounded by markup e.g. ``` {audit log} ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the screenshot you will see the audit lists where the vulnerability was patched:

```
patched in {version}
```

for example:

```
package braces
patched in >=2.3.1
```

Accordingly to fix the vulnerability you need to update the `braces` package to at least version `2.3.1` or higher.

You can do this with npm:

```
npm install --save braces@>=2.3.1
```

or if you use yarn:

```
yarn add braces@>=2.3.1
```

or follow any of the other semantic versioning rules here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/semantic-versioning-using-npm